# Sorting Algorithm: Select 5 as the smallest and 0 as the largest in a list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Hey guys can you help me out with writing a comparison function that would be use in comparison sorting algorithm. This is the standard function, but the number 5 must be regarded as being the lowest and 0 the largest.

So if we have data like this the numbers

```
0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4, 632, 0, 7
```

would be sorted to

```
5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 632, 0, 0, 0
```

Here is pseudocode; no specific language.

```
int mycompar(int a, int b) 
{ 
  if (a > b) return 1; 
  if (a < b) return -1; 
  if (a == b) return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you've already tried and what you're having trouble with? We can't just answer homework questions for you. :-)

Comment: Add this to your list of ifs: if(a==5) return -1; if(a==0) return 1;

Comment: nice job asking a simple question that everybody got wrong, most of us repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int mycompar(int a, int b) {
    if ( a == b ) return 0;
    if ( a == 5 || b == 0 ) return -1;
    if ( a == 0 || b == 5 ) return  1;
    return ( a > b ) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This code should work.

Comment: `return ( a > b )` returns a `boolean` but you should be returning an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
int mycompar(int a, int b) 
{ 
  if (a==b) return 0;
  if (a==0 || b==5) return 1;
  if (a==5 || b==0) return -1;
  if (a>b) return 1; 
  if (a<b) return -1;   
}
```

0 will always be higher than any other number and rise to the top, and 5 will always be lower than any other number and sink to the bottom.

EDIT: Check first and foremost if the number is 5 or 0.

Comment: a of 5 b of 3 is counter

Comment: @RubixRechvin In the OP's questions, 0 is higher than 5. I have edited my answer, this should work now.

Comment: a=1, b=5? It returns -1.

Comment: @genisage You're right, I have edited my answer and I will upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

The following C code works:

```
int mycompar(int a, int b){
    int MAX = 5, MIN = 0;
    return ( a==MAX || b==MIN ? -1 : ( b==MAX || a==MIN ? 1 : a-b) );
}
```